# Not so seamless pattern in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns

[image: wrapping paper with Eid Mubarak]

[image: pattern outcome]

I'm making a design for a wrapping paper and created a pattern then dragged it to my swatches window to create a new swatch. I edited the pattern and checked the"size tile to art", it came out with white lines between each pattern.

Answer (score 2):

If the pattern is well done, there should be no problem.

Try to fix it changing the horizontal and vertical **spacing** and setting the horizontal and vertical **overlapping**.

[image]